# org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: solidity, remix, web3j

I have a problem when get string value from smart contact:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Election {
    // Model a Candidate
    struct Candidate {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        uint256 voteCount;
    }

    // Store accounts that have voted
    mapping(address => bool) public voters;
    // Store Candidates
    // Fetch Candidate
    mapping(uint256 => Candidate) public candidates;
    // Store Candidates Count
    uint256 public candidatesCount;

    // voted event
    event votedEvent(uint256 indexed _candidateId);

    constructor() public {
        addCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addCandidate("Candidate 2");
    }

    //vote condinate name
    event voteCandidatEvent(string[] _arr);

    function getListCandidate() public returns (string[] memory) {
        string[] memory arr = new string[](candidatesCount);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < candidatesCount; i++) {
            Candidate memory _candidate = candidates[i];
            arr[i] = _candidate.name;
        }

        emit voteCandidatEvent(arr);
        return arr;
    }

    function addCandidate(string memory _name) public {
        candidatesCount++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
    }

    function vote(uint256 _candidateId) public {
        // require that they haven't voted before
        require(!voters[msg.sender]);

        // require a valid candidate
        require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidatesCount);

        // record that voter has voted
        voters[msg.sender] = true;

        // update candidate vote Count
        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount++;

        // trigger voted event
        emit votedEvent(_candidateId);
    }
}
```

I compiled the contract via `solcjs Election.sol --bin --abi --optimize -o ./output`, and then generate java code with web3j-4.0.1.

When I call function `getVoteCandidatEventEvents`, the error below is raised:

```
Election_sol_Election.VoteCandidatEventEventResponse recipt = contract.getVoteCandidatEventEvents(contract.getListCandidate().send()).get(0);
                String s = recipt._arr.get(0);

Exception : org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

These are different data types and you must convert what type of data it is to store it as a String.

Convert from String to byte[]:

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Convert from byte[] to String:

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 99, (byte)97, (byte)116};
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

You should, of course, use the correct encoding name. My examples used US-ASCII and UTF-8, the two most common encodings.

Answer taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but I got the same error. I think the problem is about web3j Library and it can't get a array as function result